# ActiveRecord Concern spec fails when uses self.class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, activesupport-concern

I have next `Siteable` concern:

```
module Siteable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    belongs_to :site

    scope :by_site,  lambda { |site| where(site_id: site.try(:id)) }
    scope :for_site, lambda { |site| by_site self.class.by_site(site).any? ? site : nil }
  end
end
```

Example model with this concern:

```
class IndustryLink < LinkResource
  require 'concerns/siteable.rb'
  include Siteable

  belongs_to :author, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :industry
  validates_presence_of :name, :link
end
```

It work fine on the server. But all specs with this model fails with similar errors:

```
 Failure/Error: industry = Factory(:industry, :name => 'new industry')
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `by_site' for Class:Class
 # ./app/models/concerns/siteable.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Siteable>'
 # ./app/models/industry_link.rb:12:in `get_objects'
 # ./app/models/concerns/reorderable.rb:47:in `add_number'
 # ./spec/views/sitemap/show.xml.builder_spec.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

So, obviously that `self.class` is not `Industry` in this case and I don't know how to fix this.

If I move `for_site` to model and change `self.class` to `Industry` specs passes.

Checked for ruby 1.9.3, 2.1.1, Rails 3.2.19

Comment: You are including the module which means that the methods are available to object instances. Did you try extending the module instead of including it. It will then add the methods in the module as class methods.

Comment: Forget about this, i'll try now.

Comment: It doesn't work. This actually proper way, when concern `extend ActiveSupport::Concern` and model `include` concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your lambda self is already the model class - `Industry`, so the `self.class` is [`Class`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Class.html)

You should just be using `by_site` (possibly unscoping it first, depending on what you need)